# How to pass a start and end date to a report in Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I am using Google Data Studio to show reports for a specific date range.

The date range is dynamic, calculated by a previous step, and I want the Data Studio report to have its date range setting initialized to these dynamic values when the user loads the report.

I have already created a custom query which checks if a date is between `@DS_START_DATE` and `@DS_END_DATE` (the parameters provided by Data Studio from the date range control). This successfully returns a properly filtered list when set with the report control.

How do I set DS_START_DATE and DS_END_DATE from the query string of the report as an URL parameter? They do not show up in the list of allowable URL parameters. How else can I initialize the report with a specific date range that is calculated, not set by the user?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your data from the parameters in the url. Create two parameters

- dateStart
- dateEnd

Use those parameters in your custom query instead of DS_START_DATE and DS_END_DATE.
For the date picker, choose "Auto date range". In your post, its not clear where you data is coming from, bigquery, googlesheet, firebase,etc. The auto date range might select the complete date range found in the returned data therefore showing the range you selected in the param in your url. It depends on the source of you data.

Then the date picker will filter within the returned data.